# A man is known to speak truth 3 out of 5 times. He throws a die and reports that it is a 6. The probability that it is actually a 4?

Tags: probability

> A man is known to speak truth 3 out of 5 times. He throws a die and reports that it is a 6. The probability that it is actually a 4?

The statement in the question is already happened i.e die rolled and the man reported of the outcome from the die.

Conditions:

1.The man will report the number from $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ (Always say "The die is a ____")

My approach:

Let, The event of reporting 6 on the dice by the man $\equiv A$,

The event of getting six on the dice $\equiv S_1$,

The event of getting four on the dice $\equiv S_2$,

The event of getting other than six, four  on the dice $\equiv S_3$,

Therefore, $P(S_1)=\frac{1}6$,  $P(S_2)=\frac{1}6$,  $P(S_3)=\frac{4}6$

$P(A/S_1)={\text{Probability of reporting 6 when it is actually six on the dice}\\ =\text{probability of speaking truth of the man}=\frac{3}5}$

$P(A/S_2)={\text{Probability of reporting 6 when it is actually four on the dice}\\ =\text{probability of speaking lie of the man}=\frac{2}5}$

$P(A/S_3)={\text{Probability of reporting 6 when it is actually other than four, six on the dice}\\ =\text{probability of speaking lie of the man}=\frac{2}5}$

Now, According to the Bayes' Theorem,

Probability of "The man has reported 6 when it is actually four on the dice"

$=P(S_2/A)= \frac{P(S_2)\cdot P(A/S_2)}{\sum P(S_i)\cdot P(A/S_i)}=\frac{\frac{1}{6}\cdot \frac{2}{5}}{\frac{1}{6}\cdot \frac{3}{5}+\frac{1}{6}\cdot \frac{2}{5}+\frac{4}{6}\cdot \frac{2}{5}}=\frac{2}{13}$

Comment: You should link to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4795090/a-man-is-known-to-speak-truth-3-out-of-4-times-he-throws-a-die-and-reports-that?noredirect=1#comment10196515_4795090) as that's what motivates this post.  As pointed out to you there, the answer is crucially dependent on the assumptions, but you do not provide your assumptions here.

Comment: It needs to be clarified exactly how the man will act in each case.  So, the man rolls the die and looks at it, and then decides if he is to tell the truth or to lie.  Sure.  If he decides to tell the truth, he does so by making a statement of the form "*The die is a ____*"?  Or does he ever have a chance of saying instead a statement of the form "*The die is not a ____*"?  In the event he decides to lie, how does he select which if any of the other numbers to use in the lie?  Does he always use a $6$ when lying if available?  Or does he choose one of the five inaccurate numbers uniformly?

Answer (score 1):

### Assumptions about the problem statement:

Our person will first decide whether to lie or not.  They will then throw the die which is assumed to be a fair six-sided die.  In the event they choose to be truthful, they will make a true statement of the form "*The die roll is ____*" stating what the result of the die is.  In the event they choose to lie, they will look at the result of the die, will then somehow pick uniformly at random another of the possible results of the die which is not the actual result of the die and will make a false statement of the form "*The die roll is ____*".

---

### Events:

$T$:  Our person is telling the truth.

$T^c=L$:  Our person is lying.

$S_n$:  Our person *says* that the result is $n$, whether truthful or otherwise (*So $S_6$ is the event our person says the die shows a 6*)

$A_n$:  The *actual* result of the die is $n$ (*So $A_4$ is the event that the dieroll was a $4$*)

We know since the die is fair that $\Pr(A_1)=\Pr(A_2)=\dots=\Pr(A_6) = \frac{1}{6}$.  We know from the problem statement that $\Pr(T)=0.6$ and $\Pr(L)=0.4$.

We know (*and here is where it varies from your attempt*) that $\Pr(S_6\mid A_4) = \frac{1}{5}\times 0.4$ and more generally that $\Pr(S_i\mid A_j) = 0.6$ if $i=j$ but is equal to $\frac{1}{5}\times 0.4$ if $i\neq j$.  That is to say, given that a 4 was actually rolled, for our person to say that it was a $6$ it must be that they are lying and the selected lie to say was that it was a $6$ as opposed to one of the several other available lies.

---

We are asked to find $\Pr(A_4\mid S_6)$.  We rearrange this by Bayes' Theorem.

$\Pr(A_4\mid S_6) = \dfrac{\Pr(S_6\mid A_4)\Pr(A_4)}{\Pr(S_6)}$

For $S_6$, this occurs precisely when either a $6$ is actually rolled and our person tells the truth, or when a $6$ is not rolled, the person is lying, and the randomly selected lie to tell is that what was rolled was a $6$.

$=\dfrac{\frac{1}{5}\times 0.4 \times \frac{1}{6}}{\Pr(A_6\cap T)+\Pr(A_6^c\cap L\cap S_6)}$

$=\dfrac{\frac{1}{5}\times 0.4\times \frac{1}{6}}{\frac{1}{6}\times 0.6 + 0.4\times \frac{5}{6}\times \frac{1}{5}}$

$$=\dfrac{2}{25}$$

---

Compare this to the problem where the assumptions are all the same except that every lie that is made would be done using the largest available false number which is different from what is actually rolled.  Note that this scenario is bogus and certain statements made by the man will be obviously verifiable such as if the man stated "The roll is a 3" we know with 100% certainty that the roll is in fact a 3 since if he were lying there would be no way that he would have chosen this as the statement to make.  The only ambiguous statements then that we would be unsure of would be those where the statement was "The die roll is a 5" and those where the statement was "The die roll is a 6."

Your work answers the problem if it occurred in this second scenario.

Comment: Sorry I can't agree with you. $\Pr(S_6\mid A_4) = \frac{1}{5}\times 0.4$. If he has $n$ possible way to lie, the probabiliy will change with factor $1/n$. By the statement "A man is known to speak truth 3 out of 5 times" mean if he tell lie it will always $2/5$ probability without looking number of possible way to lie.

Comment: @OM $\Pr(L) = \frac{2}{5} = \Pr(L\mid A_4) = \Pr(L\cap (S_1\cup S_2\cup S_3\cup S_5\cup S_6)\mid A_4)$ which of course expands as $ = \Pr(S_1 \mid A_4)+\Pr(S_2\mid A_4)+\Pr(S_3\mid A_4)+\Pr(S_5\mid A_4)+\Pr(S_6\mid A_4)$  I am not contradicting that he tells *some* lie with probability $\frac{2}{5}$... I am talking about the probability that he tells *a specific lie* out of the several available lies.

Comment: I am talking about $\Pr(S_6\mid A_4)$ which is not "*the probability that he says the result is a six given that it was actually a four* **and that if he decides to lie it must be a six**"... that *would* be equal to $\frac{2}{5}$.  I am talking about the probability that he says the result is a six given that it was actually a four *and he has the option to give any available plausible lie with equal probability*.

Comment: Notice how if we add up all of the possibilities given a 4 was rolled we get (Said it was a 4 given it was a 4) + (Said it was a 1 given it was a 4) + (Said it was a 2 given it was a 4) + ... + (Said it was a 6 given it was a 4) which is $0.6 + \frac{1}{5}\times 0.4 + \frac{1}{5}\times 0.4 + \frac{1}{5}\times 0.4 + \frac{1}{5}\times 0.4 + \frac{1}{5}\times 0.4 = 1$ which is what we should have expected whereas your broken logic would seem to suggest that you think the overall probabilities would or should add up as $0.6 + 0.4 + 0.4 +0.4 +0.4 +0.4 = 2.4$ which is patently absurd.

Comment: If you insist that $\Pr(S_6\mid A_4) = 0.4$ then the only way that works is if you insist on $\Pr(S_5\mid A_4)=0$ and $\Pr(S_3\mid A_4)=0$ and so on... which you claim otherwise and which as alluded to earlier is a terrible assumption that leads to a particularly uninteresting "*game*" to play with this person given your extremely high likelihood of understanding what the roll actually is since again... every time they say the roll was something $1$-$4$ you know they must be telling the truth.

Comment: Again... do not conflate $\Pr(S_6\mid A_4)$ with $\Pr((S_1\cup S_2\cup S_3\cup S_5\cup S_6)\mid A_4)$.  Do not conflate telling a *specific* lie with the act of lying in general.